# Not able to build docker-compose up - getting error The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, docker-compose, protractor, dockerfile

I have two e2e automation framework , one is python based other is protractor based. I need to write a docker-compose file to run these two projects in different containers and fetch reports and their console to my local system.

below are the contents of my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  e2e-Tests:
    build: ./c8y/DockerFile
    image: e2etests
    command: npm run e2e
    container_name: cn-e2eTests
  py-Tests:
    build: ./py/DockerFile
    image: pytests
    command: npm run e2e
    container_name: cn-pyTests
```

When I run docker-compose up , I get the below error :

```
Building e2e-Tests
failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.
[+] Building 0.0s (0/1)
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)                                                         om sender: walk \\?\C:\Users\xxx\e2e\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the path specified.
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 105B                                       0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
ERROR: Service 'e2e-Tests' failed to build
```

Comment: What's your **specific** technical question?

Comment: I am a beginner in this. Looked into docker-compose tutorials but not able to get how to start with the above problem statement.

Comment: @KlausD. updated description.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is the issue here, partially because the error is obscured in the terminal output. See the line `failed to get console mode for stdout...`? That's what is causing the error to be obscured. I don't get this issue when I run it in Ubuntu, in WSL2. It would be good to see what the error says in full.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename: `Dockerfile` instead of `DockerFile`.

**Edit:**
When the docker file name is not provided explicitly, it will look for the file `Dockerfile` with a small `f`. My issue was as simple that.

Comment: Please add more description into your question. Though the answer maybe correct solution, it is unclear what happen and it take some effort to see the `f` vs `F`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to registry access issues. It works fine now.